# Get statistics for firebase dynamic link in flutter project

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using firebase dynamic links and to fetch analytics data I am using REST API provided by dynamic link analytics API. But in this case, the URL takes parameters for only duration days, but my requirement is to find the analytics data into the duration of 1 month, like analytics data for only January month. How should I achieve this?

I am using REST API provided in this document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/analytics

Comment: Can you share a code snippet of your implementation?